# Down-sizing/custom jOOQ build?

Tags: java, sql, minimize, jooq

I have a database-heavy distributable java application that's currently only 400k. We need improved database query building as well as support for a few specific database dialects.

jOOQ has to be shaded into our JAR and it balloons it up to 1.6MB, even when using the `minimizeJar` elements for shade.

Is there a way I can do a custom build or strip out the components of jOOQ that we have no use for right now? Dialects, non insert/select/delete query classes, other features we don't need?

I thought about trying to identify every imported class that we're using and setting maven to only shade those, but I'd also need to handle classes jOOQ uses internally and I don't know how reliant jOOQ is on everything.

If I could strip it down to a few hundred k, I'd be sold on continuing to use it.

Comment: For the reference of future visitors, this question is also being discussed on [this thread on the jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/7YxAH2n9GGI/3nsIgRHrz5gJ)

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ is a domain-specific language implemented according to the principles explained here:
http://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/

This means that every "production" or "primary" from the DSL specification generates a Java interface with all the overhead this may generate in the class loader. Additionally, since jOOQ 3.0, record and row types with degree 1-22 were introduced (e.g. org.jooq.Row1, org.jooq.Row2, ... org.jooq.Row22). All of these elements are part of the API, which probably cannot be stripped down any further.

Of course, you can try to manually strip down the jOOQ API and implementation, removing all the row types from it. Another entire statement that you might not need is the MERGE statement, which also has an extensive API. Then, there are the tools packages, which aren't strictly needed, specifically:

- org.jooq.tools.csv
- org.jooq.tools.json
- org.jooq.types
- org.jooq.util.[dialect]

Also, you can try to remove a couple of classes from the org.jooq.impl package. The class names should be fairly straight-forward to help you decide whether something is needed.

It would be interesting to see how far you get with such measures. This might be useful for Android users, too.

Comment: So would you recommend that I download the source, and run a custom build, trying to strip out the features I don't need? This list you provided sounds promising... at least worth some attempt.

Comment: @BotskoNet: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. From what I know, you might be breaking new grounds. It would be very interesting for the community to learn from your findings. Note that if reducing and building the sources is too tedious, you might also be lucky by simply removing binary classes for your experiments

Comment: So far I'm not seeing enough of a result to warrant continuing. I've run builds from source in which I remove the items you suggested, plus a few other classes, but the compressed size of the end result (jOOQ) jar is still around 1.1MB, down from 1.3MB. Our plugin is 400k, so a combined total of 1.5MB is going to hurt our rep for being light weight. If I were developing an app where no cared about download size, I'd use jOOQ no question.

Comment: My goal is to keep our combined plugin below 900k. I'd really like to use jOOQ but I'm not sure that's possible. Some people have suggested ormLite which I may try. My goal is mainly to find something that lets me build queries dynamically, that supports multiple database formats. Actual "active record" type stuff isn't important to me.

Comment: OK, I see. Well if you want to stay below 900k, I'm afraid that you might need to stick with JDBC or at the most add something like [Apache DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/). 900k is really a very low limit for "modern" Java programs...

Comment: I'd rather just change the stigma in this particular field that a 1.5MB plugin isn't too big. It's hard to though when every single plugin is below 800k and our competition is already around 400k